# Typescript - extending type interface not working

Tags: typescript

I have a legacy code I am working with in typescript. Amongst others there is a base type `PackageProps` from which some other types are extended in the app like `Package`, and `ShipmentProps` and then `Shipment` extends `ShipmentProps`, like you can see it in the code below:

```
interface PackageProps {
  id: IdType,
  departmentId: DepartmentIdType,
  orderId: OrderIdType
  ... plenty more properties
}

export interface Package extends ImmutableMap<PackageProps> {
}

export interface ShipmentProps extends PackageProps {
  id: number,
  noOfPackages: number,
  packages: List<Package>,
  packageIds: Set<PackageIdType>,
  ... plenty more properties
}

export interface Shipment extends ImmutableMap<ShipmentProps> {
}
```

First of all I don't understand why there has to be for each type a type with props and then a "regular" type that is being exported?

I have tried to make my own type which would extend the `ShipmentProps` type like this:

```
interface CustomShipmentProps extends ShipmentProps {
  firstLeg?: OrderWithPackagesEntity
  lastLeg?: OrderWithPackagesEntity
  flightLeg: OrderWithPackagesEntity
}

export interface CustomShipment extends ImmutableMap<CustomShipmentProps> {
}
```

But, if I use this type, properties are not recognised:

```
const customShipment: CustomShipment = {
      firstLeg,
      flightLeg,
      lastLeg,
}
```

I get an error:

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'firstLeg' does
> not exist in type 'CustomShipment'.

What am I doing wrong here, why are properties not recognised on the type `CustomShipment`?

If I move this properties to `CustomShipment` type:

```
export interface CustomShipment extends ImmutableMap<CustomShipmentProps> {
  firstLeg?: OrderWithPackagesEntity
  lastLeg?: OrderWithPackagesEntity
  flightLeg: OrderWithPackagesEntity
}
```

Then I get the same error from above for properties that are defined on `ShipmentProps` or `PackageProps` from which `CustomShipment` extends.
How should I set this up in order to get the properties from the whole chain `PackageProps`, `ShipmentProps` and `CustomShipmentProps`?

**Update:** `ImmutableMap` is a type defined here:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable'

export function ImmutableMapFactory<T>(obj: T): ImmutableMap<T> {
    return Map(obj) as ImmutableMap<T>
}

export interface ImmutableMap<T> extends Map<any, any> {
    get<K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K]
    get<K extends keyof T>(name: K, notSetValue: T[K]): T[K]
    set<K extends keyof T>(name: K, value: T[K]): this
    merge<K extends keyof T>(...collections: Iterable<[K, T[K]]>[]): Map<K, T[K]>
    merge<K extends keyof T>(...collections: { K: T[K] }[]): Map<K, T[K]>
    update<K extends keyof T>(key: K, notSetValue: T[K], updater: (value: T[K]) => T[K]): this
    update<K extends keyof T>(key: K, updater: (value: T[K]) => T[K]): this
    update<R>(updater: (value: this) => R): R
}
```

Comment: What is `ImmutableMap`?

Comment: I have added it to question @VMaharajh